# Best practice for keeping a config file in python

Tags: python, config

I have a python script in which I have a config file which looks like this:

```
PROD = 'production'
DEV = 'dev'
ENVIRONMENT = None
```

and I have a function which gets the wanted environment from a command argument and sets it like:

```
if sys.argv[1] in [config.PROD, config.DEV]:
    config.ENVIRONMENT = sys.argv[1]
```

I understood it's not good practice when I started importing the config file in multiple files and ENV kept resetting back to None.

So, my question is: what is the best practice is this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what the best practice is but I like using JSON files. I use the following class as a layer of abstraction for interfacing with the config (properties) file. You can create one JSONPropertiesFile and pass it around your application.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
import os
from stat import * # ST_SIZE etc
from datetime import datetime
from copy import deepcopy


class JSONPropertiesFileError(Exception):
    pass


class JSONPropertiesFile(object):

    def __init__(self, file_path, default={}):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self._default_properties = default
        self._validate_file_path(file_path)

    def _validate_file_path(self, file_path):
        if not file_path.endswith(".json"):
            raise JSONPropertiesFileError(f"Must be a JSON file: {file_path}")
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            self.set(self._default_properties)

    def set(self, properties):
        new_properties = deepcopy(self._default_properties)
        new_properties.update(properties)
        with open(self.file_path, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(new_properties, file, indent=4)


    def get(self):
        properties = deepcopy(self._default_properties)
        with open(self.file_path) as file:
            properties.update(json.load(file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict))
        return properties

    def get_file_info(self):
        st = os.stat(self.file_path)
        res = {
            'size':st[ST_SIZE],
            'size_str':str(round(st[ST_SIZE]/1000,2)) + ' KB',
            'last_mod': datetime.fromtimestamp(st[ST_MTIME]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
         }
         return res
```

In your case you might use it like this:

```
file_path = "path/to/your/config/file"
default_properties = {
    'PROD': 'production',
    'DEV': 'dev',
    'ENVIRONMENT': ""
} 
config_file = JSONPropertiesFile(file_path, default_properties)
config = config_file.get() 
print(config["PROD"])
config["PROD"] = "something else"
config_file.set(config) #  save new config
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think this solution is a bit overkill and won't look nice.
In my (non-working) solution, in order to access the ENV, you call config.ENV and you're done.
In yours, you have to call JSONPropertiesFile.get()['ENV'], and while it is very robust, I believe it is not pretty (and also requires reading/writing from/to a file)

Comment: I can understand this being overkill. It is possible to turn my solution into something that would allow you to do .ENV on it, although that would just make it more complicated. Are you wanting to load it from the file system once and then not every do anything again with the file system?